# Loading pandas table with column names and dtypes

Tags: python, pandas, python-3.6

I'm fairly new to using Pandas and I seem to be having some trouble loading a table from a textfile.

Here's an example of what the data looks like:

```
#    Header text
#    Header text
# id col1 col2 col3 col4
0 0.44:66 0 1600 45.6e-3
1 0.25:7f 0 1600 52.1e-3
2 0.31:5e 0 1600 33.7e-3
...
2500 0.42.6f 0 1400 42.1e-3
# END
# Footer text
```

I am reading it in as follows:

```
import pandas as pd

with open(filename, 'rt') as f:
    df = pd.read_table(f, skiprows=2, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
```

Then when I `print(df.dtypes)` I get the following:

```
# id        int64
col1        object
col2        int64
col3        int64
col4        float64
dtype: object
```

This is fine, except for the `#` in the name of the first column. So I tried specifying the names:

```
df = pd.read_table(f, skiprows=2, skipfooter=2, engine='python', 
                   names=["id", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"])
```

but then I get `print(df.dtypes)`

```
id          object
col1        object
col2        object
col3        object
col4        object
dtype: object
```

So I tried specifying both `names` and `dtypes`:

```
df = pd.read_table(f, skiprows=2, skipfooter=2, engine='python', 
                   names=["id", "col1", "col2", "col3", "col4"], 
                   dtypes={"id":int,"col1":str,"col2":int, "col3":int,"col4":float})
```

but this gives an error:

```
ValueError: Unable to convert column id to type <class 'int'>
```

What's wrong? How can I load the table with the column `names` I want and the appropriate `dtypes`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few comments.

Firstly, I don't understand why your code works at all, given that your columns appear to be separated by whitespace (?). You'd usually require an extra `sep=' '` in the call to `read_table` or `read_csv`.

Secondly, you don't need to open the file first, you can just pass the filename to the pandas function: `pd.read_table(filename, ...)`

But to answer your question:

If you specify the column names explicitly with `names=[...]` and they don't match the header of the file, pandas assumes there is no header. You therefore have to skip an additional row (`skiprows=3`), or else pandas will assume that line is part of the table data and thus set the data type to `object` (i.e. strings) for all columns.

Answer (score 1):

I have found a workaround solution but I am open to better solutions if they are out there.

I loaded the table without specifying the `names` or `dtypes` and then renamed the problematic column name as:

```
df = pd.read_table(f, skiprows=2, skipfooter=2, engine='python')
df.rename(columns={'# id':'id'}, inplace=True)
```

Then I used `print(df.dtypes)` to get the desired output:

```
id          int64
col1        object
col2        int64
col3        int64
col4        float64
dtype: object
```

Answer (score 0):

Use astype

```
df['id'] = df['id'].astype(int)
```